# How to parse raw values from JSON array items with Jackson?

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization, json-deserialization

Using Jackson deserialization it would be great to have an option
to deserialize **JSON array of items** (of any nature: object, number, string) to a **Java array of String**.

I see that `@JsonRawValue` allows to have similar functionality for nested fields.
Is it possible to implement the same for "top level" objects?

```
void test(){
    var payload = """ [
          {"a": 1, "b": "hello"},
          {"a": 2, "b": "bye"},
          "something"
    ]
    """;

    // What else is required to get the effect of @JsonRawValue ?

    String[] rawItems = new ObjectMapper().readValue(payload, String[].class);

    assertEquals("""{"a": 1, "b": "hello"}""", rawItems[0]);
    assertEquals("""{"a": 2, "b": "bye"}""", rawItems[1]);
    assertEquals("\"something\"", rawItems[2]);
}
```

Comment: Will Jackson permit this malformed JSON? `something` is not a key-value pair, isn't it? Or is your question about allowing such strings also?

Comment: @SreeKumar According to the spec, this is a valid JSON. I would expect Jackson to handle it normally at least when parsing it into JsonNode structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert the `payload` to `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ArrayNode`  and then iterate through elements (`JsonNode` in this case) and add them to a `List<String>` (which you can then convert to `String[]` if you want).

One thing to be aware of - the formatting will not be as you expect. `JsonNode` has two methods - `toString()` which deletes all the white space and `toPrettyString` which adds whitespaces and newlines to the final `String`

```
        String payload = """ 
        [
          {"a": 1, "b": "hello"},
          {"a": 2, "b": "bye"},
          "something"
        ]
        """;
        ArrayNode items = new ObjectMapper().readValue(payload, ArrayNode.class);

        List<String> rawItemsList = new ArrayList<>();

        for (JsonNode jsonNode : items) {
            rawItemsList.add(jsonNode.toString());
        }

        // You can just keep using the rawItemsList, but I've converted it to array since the question mentioned it
        String[] rawItemsArr = rawItemsList.toArray(new String[0]);

        assertEquals("""
                {"a":1,"b":"hello"}""", rawItemsArr[0]);
        assertEquals("""
                {"a":2,"b":"bye"}""", rawItemsArr[1]);
        assertEquals("\"something\"", rawItemsArr[2]);
```